# HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode() = java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

```
ByteArrayOutputStream i4 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
i4.write(("--" + i3 + System.lineSeparator() + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + I1.this.i2 + "\"; filename=\"" + I1.this.i2 + ".jpg\"" + System.lineSeparator() + "Content-Type: " + HttpURLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(I1.this.i2 + ".jpg") + System.lineSeparator() + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes());
i4.flush();
i4.write(i2.this.i1);
i4.flush();
i4.write((System.lineSeparator() + "--" + i3 + "--" + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes());
i4.flush();
i4.close();
HttpURLConnection i5 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("***").openConnection();
i5.setRequestMethod("POST");
i5.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
i5.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + i3);
OutputStream i6 = i5.getOutputStream();
i6.write(i4.toByteArray());
i6.flush();
i6.close();
i5.getResponseCode(); // ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
i5.disconnect();
```

Что в моём коде не так? Почему вылетает `java.io.EOFException`? На Android 4.2 всё идеально работало, но как только установил это же приложение с этим кодом на новый телефон Android версии 4.4.2 вдруг происходит такая проблема.

Вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258518/android-httpurlconnection-eofexception), [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641374/android-eofexception-when-using-httpurlconnection-headers), и [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319194/android-httpurlconnection-throwing-eofexception), к сожалению, не решает проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо заменить

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

на старые добрые

```
\r\n
```

строки. Всего-то, казалось бы, мелочь, однако портит всё.